# Example of locally Hamiltonian but not Hamiltonian graph.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

**Question.**

A graph is a locally Hamiltonian graph if for every vertex $v$ induced subgraph $G(N(v))$ is Hamiltonian.

Give an example of a locally Hamiltonian but not Hamiltonian graph.

**Part of the solution that I came to**

This planar triangulation (Pic 1.) is locally Hamiltonian but not a Hamiltonian graph.

*How to prove it?*

[image: Pic 1.]
**Pic 1.**

Comment: How do you know that the pictured graph is a solution, if you don't know how to prove it?  Is it an example you found somewhere?

Comment: @saulspatz It is a solution I found in the book with this problem. Now I want to prove that this solution is correct.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I can see that it's easy to check that it's locally Hamiltonian, but how do you manually check that it's not Hamiltonian?

Comment: @saulspatz I've posted a method to quickly *demonstrate* that this graph is not Hamiltonian, but of course there's no (known) method to always quickly check a graph for Hamiltonicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any planar triangulation will be locally Hamiltonian. I'm not sure if your definition of $N(v)$ includes the vertex $v$ itself, but it works either way. We can take a plane embedding (so, the edge $(1,5)$ in your drawing should be bent to avoid crossing $(2,3)$)  and go around the neighbors of any vertex $v$ in clockwise order of the edges out of $v$. This will always form a cycle. If we want to include $v$ in the cycle as well, we can insert it at any point.

To see that this planar triangulation is not Hamiltonian, consider the vertex coloring below (vertices $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ are red, and vertices $\{2,4,6,8,10,11\}$ are blue).

[image]

This coloring has the property that each blue vertex has only red neighbors. So, if there is a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph, then (if we give the Hamiltonian cycle a direction) the vertex that comes after every blue vertex must be red.

However, there are $6$ blue vertices, and only $5$ red vertices. That's not enough for a red vertex to come after every blue vertex! So a Hamiltonian cycle cannot exist.

(Essentially, this argument works by showing that this triangulation is not [$1$-tough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_toughness), whereas all Hamiltonian graphs are $1$-tough. I suspected that this would be the case, since this is a common strategy to prove that graphs are not Hamiltonian. To find the set $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ whose removal leaves $6$ connected components, I began by including some very high-degree vertices such as $1,3,5,9$, then noticed that one of the remaining components had three vertices only "held together" by vertex $7$. This is a guessing strategy, not an algorithm.)

We can use this idea to construct many more examples of locally Hamiltonian graphs which are not Hamiltonian. Start with any $3$-edge-connected planar graph $G$ which has more faces than vertices. Then, construct a triangulation $H$ by adding a new vertex in the middle of every face of $G$, and connecting it to every vertex along that face. (If $G$ is not $3$-edge-connected, then some faces visit a vertex multiple times, and this construction fails - either $H$ will not be a simple graph, or $H$ will not be a triangulation.) The example above can be constructed in this way, by taking $G$ to be the skeleton graph of the [triangular bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_bipyramid).

The same proof works to show that $H$ is not Hamiltonian, if we color each of the old vertices red, and each of the new vertices blue.

Comment: Thank you for another masterly answer.